# Is there a better way to debug NoReverseMatch in Django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

If you change your `urls.py` or you stupidly write some template code that refers to a URL that ultimately doesn't reverse to a URL you get the infamous:

> NoReverseMatch: Reverse for `'<name>'` with arguments `'args'` and keyword arguments `'{kwargs}'` not found.

Is there a way to have the line in the template file included in the error?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write out your own implementation of the error reporting to achieve this. Template errors are traced to the point of rendering the template. This isn't super helpful but from my experience it's all there is.